# Combine list elements in groups of two with a delimiter

Tags: python, list

I have a list of words and their meanings:

```
wm = ['mendacious',
 'dishonest',
 'mendicant',
 'beggar',
 'meretricious',
 'gaudy; specious; falsely attractive',
 'mesmerize',
 'to hypnotize',
 'metamorphosis',
 'change; transformation']
```

Every word is followed by its meaning. So `mendacious` means `dishonest`, `mendicant` means `beggar` and so on. Words which have multiple meanings have their meanings separated by a `;`. For example 'meretricious' has meanings `gaudy; specious; falsely attractive`.

What I want to do is to combine word-meaning pairs such that that my final list is this:

```
['mendacious : dishonest','mendicant : beggar','meretricious : gaudy; specious; falsely attractive','mesmerize : to hypnotize', 'metamorphosis : change; transformation']
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Simply run over even indices in `for` loop.

Comment: Have you tried: `dict(zip(wm[1:], wm))` ?

Comment: @JonClements I don't think this does what the OP is looking for. Though a `dict` is probably a better structure for the OP (perhaps not in reverse) - `i = iter(wm); dict(zip(i, i))`

Comment: @AChampion yes... it almost looks like the OP wants a dict (without knowing it), however if they want strings, then fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterator over the list in pairs, and there's a simple idiom to do this by `zip`ing up 2 of the same `iter`:

```
>>> i = iter(wm)
>>> [' : '.join(s) for s in zip(i, i)]
['mendacious : dishonest',
 'mendicant : beggar',
 'meretricious : gaudy; specious; falsely attractive',
 'mesmerize : to hypnotize',
 'metamorphosis : change; transformation']
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly declare another variable as an `iter` here - you can use `[' : '.join(s) for s in [iter(wm)] * 2]` instead

Comment: @JonClements Yes, you can get away without defining `i` (yours is missing the `zip`) but I find it can be harder for new folks to follow as it uses a bit more magic `[' : '.join(s) for s in zip(*[iter(wm)]*2)]`. The principle is the same, using the same iterator twice to step through the list 2 at a time.

Comment: Yeah - sorry missed the `*` :p

Comment: @JonClements And `zip()` :p

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a list of tuples using this code:

```
tl = zip(wm[0::2], wm[1::2])
```

This list will look like the following list:

```
[('mendacious', 'dishonest'), ('mendicant', 'beggar'), ('meretricious', 'gaudy; specious; falsely attractive'), ('mesmerize', 'to hypnotize'), ('metamorphosis', 'change; transformation')]
```

Then you can iterate through this list and concatenate each tuple.

#### #1

```
output = map(lambda t: t[0] + ':' + t[1], tl)
```

#### #2

```
output = [':'.join(t) for t in tl]
```

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic way of doing it:

```
res = ["%s : %s" % (wm[i], wm[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(wm), 2)]
print(res)

['mendacious : dishonest','mendicant : beggar','meretricious : gaudy; specious; falsely attractive','mesmerize : to hypnotize', 'metamorphosis : change; transformation']
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very similar to AChampion's:

```
wm = [
    'mendacious',
    'dishonest',
    'mendicant',
    'beggar',
    'meretricious',
    'gaudy; specious; falsely attractive',
    'mesmerize',
    'to hypnotize',
    'metamorphosis',
    'change; transformation'
]

a = list(map(' : '.join, zip(*[iter(wm)] * 2)))
print(a)
```

This code may be a bit mysterious, so I'll try to explain what's going on.

[`iter(wm)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) creates an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) object from `wm`.  As the docs say, this is

> an object representing a stream of data. Repeated calls to the
>   iterator’s `__next__()` method (or passing it to the built-in function
>   `next()`) return successive items in the stream.

We then duplicate the iterator and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) it. This lets us iterate over the items from the pair of iterators in parallel. But we don't actually have two separate iterators: we have two references to the one iterator object, so what we get is successive pairs of the items in `wm`. FWIW, this technique is discussed in [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks).

We use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to call the `' : '.join` method on each tuple of strings yielded by `zip`. Finally, we use `list` to convert the iterable returned by `map` into a list (in Python 2 this step isn't needed since the Python 2 `map` returns a list).

---

We can use this same technique to produce a dictionary instead of a list. A dictionary is a more useful structure for this data.

```
d = {k: v for k, v in zip(*[iter(wm)] * 2)}
print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'metamorphosis': 'change; transformation', 'mendicant': 'beggar', 'mendacious': 'dishonest', 'mesmerize': 'to hypnotize', 'meretricious': 'gaudy; specious; falsely attractive'}
```

And we can split the `v` strings into lists, which makes it easier to get at the individual words:

```
d = {k: v.split('; ') for k, v in zip(*[iter(wm)] * 2)}
print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'mendacious': ['dishonest'], 'mesmerize': ['to hypnotize'], 'meretricious': ['gaudy', 'specious', 'falsely attractive'], 'metamorphosis': ['change', 'transformation'], 'mendicant': ['beggar']}
```