# how to implement code in python list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to understand how to write the code below using python list comprehension method. In the code I need to concatenate the string with itself times next element in the list assuming that the order is always as [string, int, string int]. Is there a way to rewrite the below code using list comprehension method? Thank you.

```
def array_translate(arr):
    i = 0
    mystring = ''
    while i < len(arr):
        pet = arr[i]
        if i + 1 < len(arr):
            num = arr[i+1]
        arr[i] = pet*num
        i += 2

    for i in arr:
        if not str(i).isdigit():
            mystring += "".join(i)
        else:
            continue
    return mystring

print (array_translate(["Cat", 2, "Dog", 3, "Mouse", 1])) # => "CatCatDogDogDogMouse"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pair items in a list, you can create an iterator from the list and zip the iterator with itself, so that you can iterate over the pairs of names and counts in a generator expression or list comprehension for `str.join` to join them into a string after repeating the strings by the respective counts:

```
def array_translate(arr):
    i = iter(arr)
    return ''.join(name * count for name, count in zip(i, i))
```

so that:

```
array_translate(["Cat", 2, "Dog", 3, "Mouse", 1])
```

returns:

```
'CatCatDogDogDogMouse'
```

Comment: this is really cool solution! Thank you so very much. Could you share any resource where I can learn about iter and zip in python?

Comment: You're welcome. You can learn about `iter` and `zip` in the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). For this particular usage, however, I learned it from StackOverflow from answers such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40565199/6890912

Answer (score 0):

If you can format it as a list of tuples, like this: `[("Cat", 2), ("Dog", 3), ("Mouse", 1)]` then the following can work.

```
''.join([a[0] * a[1] for a in array])
```

What it does is create a list strings containing an animal x times. Then ''.join() concats them together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. If you want to iterate over pairs of values, use `zip`:

```py
def array_translate(arr):
    pets = arr[0::2]
    nums = arr[1::2]
    return ''.join([ pet * num for pet, num in zip(pets, nums) ])

print(array_translate(["Cat", 2, "Dog", 3, "Mouse", 1]))
```

This works by first creating two new lists, `pets` containing just the strings, and `nums` containing just the numbers. The lists are created using slice notation: `arr[0::2]` is every 2nd element starting from index 0, and `arr[1::2]` is every 2nd element starting from index 1.

The `''.join` method is used to join the resulting strings together.

Answer (score 0):

Given `arr = ["Cat", 2, "Dog", 3, "Mouse", 1]`

Here's a one liner solution **without** `zip` or `iter`:

```py
print(''.join([arr[i]*arr[i+1] for i in range(0, len(arr), 2]))
```

Outputs:

```
CatCatDogDogDogMouse
```